# Ribbon Styles in WPF 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Good mornorning;

I have a Ribbon control in my application wpf (i work with .NET 4.5), so i work with Ribbon Control included in.NET 4.5 .

Now i want to apply a style for my Ribbon Control( like office 2007 for example) !. 
i dont know how i can do this.

can you help me please !.

```
<Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon1" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" >

  <!-- Help Pane, located at the right-hand side -->
  <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
    <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\help.png" />
  </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
  <!-- Quick Access Toolbar - located at the upper-left corner -->
  <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
    <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
      <RibbonButton x:Name ="btnSave" SmallImageSource="Images\save2.png" ToolTip="Save Changes" />
      <RibbonButton x:Name ="btnCut" SmallImageSource="Images\cut.png" ToolTip="Cut" />
      <RibbonButton x:Name ="btnCopy" SmallImageSource="Images\copy.png" ToolTip="Copy" />
      <RibbonButton x:Name ="btnPaste" SmallImageSource="Images\paste.png" ToolTip="Paste" />
    </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
  </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
```

........

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/0b73e1/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/

Comment: thank's, but in this article there isn't a way to set the Style of Ribbon control !!